# Pulling changes from fork parent in Git

Tags: git, github

How do you pull changes from the parent of a fork in Git, specifically in a github configured project?

For example, say I forked http://github.com/originaluser/originalproject into http://github.com/myuser/myproject. I don't plan on myproject on being a permanent fork, as I only want to maintain a "dev" branch to test some experimental features, and then eventually merge it back into the original project.

As such, whenever commits are made to originalproject, I want to be able to pull them down and merge them with myproject. However, I also want to be able to push changes up into myproject, but not yet immediately create a pull request to get them merged into originalproject until my branch is complete and tested. What's the best way to do this?

Edit: By default, when I create a local checkout/fork of my github fork for local development, and then push/pull changes up, these changes only effect my personal fork. I never get changes from the original project. How do I fix that?

Sorry for any incorrect git terminology.

Comment: You've described what you want to do, which is fine, but I don't see any problem to be solved here. Is this not working for you?

Comment: @GregHewgill, No. I've edited my question to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 51):

Expanding on other answers, these are the steps I took on a fork I had of tsc-watch:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/gilamran/tsc-watch.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push
```

Explained:

1. adding the remote server as `upstream` (alias)
2. fetch all changes from  the `upstream` remote
3. merge changes from `upstream/master` branch into my current branch
4. push all changes to GitHub

Comment: Thnks - you made it look easy ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can add the parent repository (upstream) as another remote branch. Something like

```
git remote add upstream ...
```

and then you can just *git fetch* to see any changes and then rebase/merge... whatever.

Comment: Clone your fork (myuser/myproject), cd into it and then type git remote add upstream https://github.com/originaluser/originalproject.git and then type git fetch. After that you should have master (your local master branch), origin/master (your remove master branch) and finally upstream/master (originalproject's master) from which you can pull changes into your repository.

Comment: You also need to specify the new remote on `git fetch`, otherwise it doesn't fetch it: `git fetch upstream` does the trick.