# In GitHub, is it possible to change the upstream project without removing my fork and forking anew?

Tags: github

Suppose I have originally created a fork of `github.com/original/bar` and the fork is at `github.com/itsme/bar`. Now in the meantime `github.com/original/bar` has been superseded and the new upstream *project* has become `github.com/new/FooBar` (itself originally forked from `original/bar`). Is there a chance for me to adjust the settings of my fork so it gets displayed as "forked from `new/FooBar`" (the new upstream *project*)? In essence is it possible to "rebase" my fork at the project level as well?

I understand this is mostly cosmetics, but aside from showing up as "forked from `original/bar`" near the project title my project will continue to show irrelevant information such as:

```
This branch is X commits ahead, Y commits behind original:master.
```

... whereas it would be much more sensible to refer to the desired new upstream repository tied to the new upstream *project*.

Is this at all possible in GitHub without outright deleting my fork and forking from the new upstream project from scratch?

**NB:** I mean the *project* indeed, not the contained Git repository. So no need to tell me about, say, [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314046/476371) or refer me [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork).